# Checking grain of a fact table

Tags: oracle

How would I check the grain of a fact table ? And how do I tell if the grain of a fact table has changed or not after adding a column to the fact table ?

Comment: Please add more information regarding your specific situation so that we can better help you

Comment: In theory, the grain of a table corresponds to its primary key. In real life, there may be a few problems with that. (1) The intended grain may not correspond exactly to the primary key - either because "the business" didn't communicate their intent clearly enough, or because the developers didn't understand it, or because they were just incompetent, or perhaps for other reasons. (2) You may not be able to identify the PK easily - some applications keep the PK designations and enforcement "in the application".

Comment: Why are you asking? Did you inherit a DB and need to figure out what's what? It would be best to find written documentation from the time the DB was originally designed and implemented. It may be possible (perhaps even easy) to find the PK for each table (which columns participate), but you will run into the issues I just described above, so that may or may not be helpful.

Comment: thanks for all your responses guys I figured it.